# OpenVPN server Failing to start

Tags: 14.04, openvpn

Currently I installed openVPN on my ubuntu 14 VPS. When I try to start it from the admin web panel I get this error:

`process started and then immediately exited: ['Thu Nov 3 11:17:49 2016 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status`

When I try to start it from the console:

`root@inforcer25:~# service openvpn start
openvpn: unrecognized service`

EDIT: Here's the tutorial I followed its also my VPS host https://www.pulseservers.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=3

Comment: Your VPS provider probably doesn't support TUN/TAP.  When you say 'admin web panel', is it part of your VPS control panel or are you referring to the 'Access Server' from OpenVPN?

Comment: Access Server from openVPN also they provided the tutorial on how to install it. https://www.pulseservers.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=3

Comment: Unfortunately your link requires a login.  FWIW, I would suggest a trouble ticket with them(pulseservers.com).